# SQL Server : update column based on sum of other columns

Tags: sql-server, database

Let's say I have table T1 with three int columns, A, B, and C.

I need to update column C after the update of both columns A and B.
This can be done by:

```
declare @one = (select col1 from T2)
    update T1 set A= @one * B
    
    update T1 set C = A+B
```

however

`update T1  set A=@one * B, C = A+B` .

Will use the values of A and B before this updated statement.

Can we join the first two statements in one statement?

Comment: It
 would be better here to post your actual code.  The answer to this trivial example I don't think will help much.  I get what you're asking, but there several ways this could go.

Comment: This is exactly my table and columns, I just changed the names of the table and the fields.

Comment: Ok, but are you really updating the values to INT literals?  If so, then the simple answer is `UPDATE T1 SET A=1, B=2, C=1+2;` but I suspect it's more involved than that in your actual code.

Comment: Also, have you considered making C a computed column?

Comment: I still think you have a problem with your example.  Your code update implies that T2 will only ever have one row in it (ignoring the fact you don't declare @one with a datatype).  The solution here is still trivial - `UPDATE T1 SET A = @one * B, C = (@one * B) + B;`

Comment: @squillman Thank you, you just lead me to something I was not aware of.